# Scrollview stretches background Android

Tags: android, android-layout, layout, background, scrollview

I have read many question on this topic but found no answer.

the problem is that I have a ScrollView as mainView in my xml and if I set a background it is stretched.

```
ScrollView(background)-->content
```

I also tried:

```
Scrollview-->content(background)
```

To solve the issue I need to wrap the scrollView inside a LinearLayout.

```
LinearLayout(background)-->ScrolView-->content
```

Now the background (if applied to the mainLinearLayout) is no more stretched but I have the warning:

```
This ScrollView layout or its LinearLayout parent is possibly useless; transfer the background attribute to the other
```

view

I'd like to have the background not stretched and also get rid of this warning.

Probably I've not fully understood how this Views work...

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 0):

Not a beautiful answer. But it should work.

- You can set the background activity in styles xml file.
- Remove useless LinearLayout.
- Set the background of scrollview to transparent.

Answer (score 0):

in your first case, use `android:layout_height="wrap_content"` for the scrollview and it won't stretch the background picture anymore